# 'No module named 'ms_identity_web' - Try to implement Azure Active Directory for Microsoft Login in Django App

Tags: django, azure, azure-active-directory

[Relevant Part in Microsoft Tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/training/modules/msid-django-web-app-sign-in/3-exercise-register-django-web-app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ow3PX.png)

I installed tha package using a bash file and running bash file in my workflow file executed in GitHub:

workflow.yml

```
 - name: Create and start virtual environment
        run: |
          python -m venv venv
          source venv/bin/activate

 - name: install MSIdentity
        run : |
          chmod +x MSIdent.sh
          ./MSIdent.sh

 - name: Install dependencies
        run: pip install -r requirements.txt
```

During Building I get the following notification:

```
  run chmod +x MSIdent.sh
  chmod +x MSIdent.sh
  ./MSIdent.sh
  shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
  env:
    pythonLocation: /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.9.16/x64
Collecting git+https://github.com/azure-samples/ms-identity-python-utilities@main
  Cloning https://github.com/azure-samples/ms-identity-python-utilities (to revision main) to /tmp/pip-req-build-d_rgygaw
  Running command git clone --filter=blob:none --quiet https://github.com/azure-samples/ms-identity-python-utilities /tmp/pip-req-build-d_rgygaw
  Resolved https://github.com/azure-samples/ms-identity-python-utilities to commit 9b32cef36c6c0b73c1b3237fdd66128d89f90a62
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
Collecting msal<2,>=1.6.0
  Downloading msal-1.21.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (89 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 89.9/89.9 kB 2.1 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting cryptography<41,>=0.6
  Downloading cryptography-40.0.2-cp36-abi3-manylinux_2_28_x86_64.whl (3.7 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 3.7/3.7 MB 44.4 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting requests<3,>=2.0.0
  Downloading requests-2.28.2-py3-none-any.whl (62 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 62.8/62.8 kB 16.2 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting PyJWT[crypto]<3,>=1.0.0
  Downloading PyJWT-2.6.0-py3-none-any.whl (20 kB)
Collecting cffi>=1.12
  Downloading cffi-1.15.1-cp39-cp39-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (441 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 441.2/441.2 kB 69.6 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting urllib3<1.27,>=1.21.1
  Downloading urllib3-1.26.15-py2.py3-none-any.whl (140 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 140.9/140.9 kB 37.0 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting idna<4,>=2.5
  Downloading idna-3.4-py3-none-any.whl (61 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 61.5/61.5 kB 16.8 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting certifi>=2017.4.17
  Downloading certifi-2022.12.7-py3-none-any.whl (155 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 155.3/155.3 kB 39.1 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting charset-normalizer<4,>=2
  Downloading charset_normalizer-3.1.0-cp39-cp39-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (199 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 199.2/199.2 kB 43.6 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting pycparser
  Downloading pycparser-2.21-py2.py3-none-any.whl (118 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 118.7/118.7 kB 34.4 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Installing collected packages: urllib3, PyJWT, pycparser, idna, charset-normalizer, certifi, requests, cffi, cryptography, msal, ms-identity-web
  DEPRECATION: ms-identity-web is being installed using the legacy 'setup.py install' method, because it does not have a 'pyproject.toml' and the 'wheel' package is not installed. pip 23.1 will enforce this behaviour change. A possible replacement is to enable the '--use-pep517' option. Discussion can be found at https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/8559
  Running setup.py install for ms-identity-web: started
  Running setup.py install for ms-identity-web: finished with status 'done'
Successfully installed PyJWT-2.6.0 certifi-2022.12.7 cffi-1.15.1 charset-normalizer-3.1.0 cryptography-40.0.2 idna-3.4 ms-identity-web-0.16.6 msal-1.21.0 pycparser-2.21 requests-2.28.2 urllib3-1.26.15

Notice:  A new release of pip is available: 23.0.1 -> 23.1
Notice:  To update, run: pip install --upgrade pip
```

Deployment is also succesful. During start-up of the Web Django App via Azure i get the error:

```
2023-04-16T10:55:23.072620824Z     mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
2023-04-16T10:55:23.072625224Z   File "/opt/python/3.9.16/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
2023-04-16T10:55:23.072629724Z     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2023-04-16T10:55:23.072634124Z   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
2023-04-16T10:55:23.072638824Z   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
2023-04-16T10:55:23.072679724Z   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2023-04-16T10:55:23.072689224Z   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
2023-04-16T10:55:23.072722424Z   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850, in exec_module
2023-04-16T10:55:23.072730124Z   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
2023-04-16T10:55:23.072734723Z   File "/tmp/MyLongNumber/MyAppName/MyAppName/settings.py", line 15, in <module>
2023-04-16T10:55:23.072739323Z     from ms_identity_web.configuration import AADConfig
2023-04-16T10:55:23.072743923Z ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ms_identity_web'
2023-04-16T10:55:23.084117523Z [2023-04-16 10:55:23 +0000] [97] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 97)
2023-04-16T10:55:23.177194902Z [2023-04-16 10:55:23 +0000] [96] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2023-04-16T10:55:23.177231402Z [2023-04-16 10:55:23 +0000] [96] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
```

I wonder what is wrong here since the package seems to be succesfully installed. I am just following the instructions in the Microsoft Tutorial. Did any body experience the same issue and can help me out here? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced the scenario in my lab based on tutorial link you shared and got the same error 'ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ms_identity_web'

It is because the module 'ms__identity__web' is not installed where the application resides and installing the modules at the temporary location.

To resolve the issue:

Navigate to the project folder to install the project dependencies(requirement.txt)

(djangoenv) .....\1-Authentication\sign-in> pip install -r requirements.txt

djangoenv is virtual environment to run Django application and pip install will install all the dependencies at above mentioned path where application is running.

Reference Sample : https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-python-django-tutorial/tree/main/1-Authentication/sign-in.